# Rearranged linked list. given a linkedlist a1 a2...an b1 b2...bn rearranged to a1 b1 a2 b2...an bn.

Tags: algorithm

Recently i read the cracking code, in the chapter 2 it introduce the runner method to solve the majority linked list problem.

Given a linkedlist a1 a2...an b1 b2...bn rearranged to a1 b1 a2 b2...an bn.

It said we should use two runner, the faster one should run as twice speed as the slower one.

Because it is even number in total, when the faster runner to the end, the slower is in the middle of the linked list. Then put the faster runner at the begin of the linked list and insert the element which pointed by the slower after the faster runner.

I know this principle, but my problem is that:

For example

1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4

At first, both two runner point to the "1",

then the faster runner points to the "3", the slower points to the "2".

the faster funner points to the second "1", the slower points to the "3".

the faster runner points to the second "3", the slower points to the "4".

And then ? what should i do?  i can't put the faster runner to the first "1", because i hasn't reached the end of the linked list. the same to the slower one, it hasn't reached to the middle of the linked list.

If i add a head to the linked list, the faster runner and the slower runner can reach the middle and end. I mean it will look like the following:

0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4;

So i want to know, if i want to use the runner method to solve this problem, should i add an index to both faster runner and slower runner?

Answer (score 1):

```
# This is a testing function by Pengyu CHEN (cpy.prefers.you[at]gmail.com)
# For answering questions on StackOverflow.com
# COPYLEFT, ALL WRONGS RESERVED.

"""
To rearrange a lst from a_1->a_2->...->a_n->b_1->b_2->...->b_n
to a_1->b_1->...->a_i->b_i->...->a_n->b_n
"""
def linked_list_rearrange(lst):
    # step 1:
    fast = lst.head
    slow = lst.head
    while fast != None:
        fast = fast.next
        fast = fast.next # assuming here it won't generage any errors
        slow = slow.next
    # step 2:
    fast = lst.head
    # now slow is at middle of the list, means b_1
    while slow != None:
        temp = slow.next
        slow.next = fast.next
        fast.next = slow
        fast = slow.next
        slow = temp
    return lst
```

Assume your are an interpreter and feed your input list to the above function. By following its steps you'll have a clear view of the algorithm I suppose.

**UPDATED:** fixed: typo from fase to fast.
**UPDATED:** added: copyright(copyleft) info.

Answer (score 0):

Think programmatically. When it says faster moves twice as fast, it means at one iteration, it takes one step, follwowed by another.

So after `the faster runner points to the second "3", the slower points to the "4".`, slower moves to second "1" while faster first moves to second "4". You need to put a check in movement of faster, if the node, which faster points to, points to `NULL` (or if it a last node in the list), move faster to first node in the list.

Then, just move the node to which slower currently points (second "1"), to after the node to which faster currently points (first "1").

HTH